# Representation of $S^1\times S^2$ as the union of two solid tori

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f,g:S^1\times S^1\to S^1\times S^1$ be the maps defined by $f(z,w)=(z,w)$ and $g(z,w)=(w,z)$. Then, $S^3=D^2\times S^1 \cup_f S^1\times D^2 $. For this, I have seen many explanations and the easiest for me is to think of $S^3$ as the boundary of $D^4$, so $$S^3=\partial(D^4)=\partial(D^2\times D^2)=D^2\times S^1 \cup_f  S^1\times D^2.$$
Is there any way to explain why $D^2\times S^1 \cup_g  S^1\times D^2=S^2\times S^1$?

Comment: $S^2=D^2\cup D^2$, hence, $S^2\times S^1= (D^2\cup D^2)\times S^1= D^2\times S^1\cup D^2\times S^1$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you explain where you used the map $g$? I would like to see $S^2\times S^1$ as the Gluing of $D^2\times S^1$ and $S^1\times D^2$ along $g$.

Comment: I don't think your maps are right. Gluing along $f$ just means you leave the $S^1$ factor in $D^2\times S^1$ alone, so you get (two disks glued together)$\times S^1$. If you think of $S^3$ as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$, then there is the torus $|z|^2=|w|^2$. It is the common boundary of two solid tori $|z|^2<|w|^2$ and $|z|^2>|w|^2$. The map $g$ just interchanges these two solid tori.

Comment: I am not using $g$, I am using $f$ ($g$ will give you $S^3$). The procedure for forming $S^2\times S^1$ using the "identity" gluing map is called "doubling".

Answer (score 0):

Let us first consider $S^3$. As you say, we have
$$S^3 = \partial D^4 \approx \partial (D^2 \times D^2) =  D^2 \times S^1 \cup S^1 \times D^2 .$$
This is an *ordinary union* of two genuine subsets of $\partial (D^2 \times D^2)$. Their intersection is $S^1 \times S^1$. But now we can identify $\partial (D^2 \times D^2)$ with the quotient space $D^2 \times S^1 \cup_f S^1 \times D^2$ obtained from the disjoint union $D^2 \times S^1 + S^1 \times D^2$ by identifying the points of $S^1 \times S^1$ in both summands via the identity map $f$. The same result is obtained if we form $D^2 \times S^1 \cup_g D^2 \times S^1$ or $S^1 \times D^2 \cup_g S^1 \times D^2$. Here we start with the disjoint union of two copies of the *same variant* of the solid torus, but need a coordinate switch for gluing. In $D^2 \times S^1 \cup_f S^1 \times D^2$ we start with homeomorphic, but formally different, variants of the solid torus and we do not need a coordinate switch for gluing. In fact, a coordinate switch for gluing is unnecessary because we have done it before by starting with "switched" variants of the solid torus. This also explains Moishe Kohan's last comment.

Now let us come to $S^2 \times S^1$. We can identify $S^2$ with $D^2 \cup_i D^2$, where $i : S^1 \to S^1$ is the identity map. Doing so, we get an identifications of $S^2 \times S^1$ with $D^2 \times S^1 \cup_f D^2 \times S^1$. If we change the perspective as above, we get
$$S^2 \times S^1 \approx D^2 \times S^1 \cup_g S^1 \times D^2 .$$
The coordinate switch for gluing is necessary to compensate starting with switched variants of the solid torus.